# Loading DXF data with original dimensions into QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, scale, dxf

I have many DXF files. And these are architectural drawings.
In QGIS, I want to place buildings in their real locations on earth, and I am preparing a plugin for this.
But when I export the DXF data to QGIS, the lines do not come to their original size.
The example is shown below.

DXF data does not contain any coordinate data. From time to time, DXF data can be scaled or in a downscaled/upscaled form. At this stage, all I want is to import the building lines in their original dimensions into QGIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try hitting the 'Cartesian' radio button on the measurement tool. Also maybe try using the 'Identify' tool on the geometry, to report on the 'Length (Cartsian - 2d) attribute value.

Comment: The Cartesian button shows the same almost same result.
I tried your answers but nothing changed.
Thank you. @nr_aus

Comment: Please upload a DXF with (sample) data

Comment: You can reach the sample data from this link. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mRvKrR8Kd6qpBxB-r33G0e-JzQeW6-1N?usp=share_link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "numbers" in the DXF are inches.
You can define a user defined crs for it in QGIS

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1  +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80  +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-in +no_defs
```

For import I recommend the plugin AnotherDXFImporter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mike, its perfect!